# Remove the remainder of a string after a certain 'phrase' in a string (R)

Tags: r, stringr, gsub

Suppose I have this object

`x <- c('keep this text except remove this part after a certain phrase','keep this part, remove everything after the comma')`

I would like to use Stringr to remove everything after (1) the word 'except' & (2) after the ','

My desired output of x is:

`'keep this text'`

`'keep this part'`

Is there a way to do that in R?

I tried using gsub, but it does not give me the output I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gsub` works fine with the correct regex:

```r
gsub('^(.*)(,| except).*$', '\\1', x)
#> [1] "keep this text" "keep this part"
```

Comment: Or `gsub("(?:\\,|except).*", "", x)`

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you very much for your response. I cannot cast a vote yet because I just opened this account. My apology!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively please try the stringr::str_remove_all

```r
str_remove_all(x,'((?=\\,).*)|((?=except).*)')

[1] "keep this text " "keep this part"
```

Answer (score 1):

To avoid complex regexes, we can remove the text sequentially with `stringr`

```
library(stringr)

x |> 
    str_remove_all(",.*") |>
    str_remove_all(" except.*")

[1] "keep this text" "keep this part"
```